# equation of tangent line and parametric equation of tangent line (are they equivalent)

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am not sure about the steps to finding parametric equations of tangent lines and was wondering if these statements are equivalent

Is there a difference if I am asked to find:

- equations of tangent lines to the parametric curve at a given point
- parametric equations of tangent lines to the parametric curve at a given point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you are asked to find the equation of a tangent line to parametric curves at a given point, it is likely that the writer of the question intends for you to give a single equation in terms of x and y, with no t.

If you are asked to find parametric equations of a tangent line to parametric curves at a given point, then your answer will involve two equations, one with x in terms of t and one with y in terms of t.

Comment: Thank you for that, seems pretty clear now!